# UICollectionView / FlowLayout

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewlayout

I'm facing a challenge when using UICollectionView and a related Layout. I'm trying to create a vertical UICollectionView with two columns, where as the cells in the left and right columns are positioned as displayed in the picture:

[image]

I do manage without problems to create the two columns but struggle finding the correct settings in my Layout in order to have the right column be offset by half the height of one cell. Note, all cells have the same calculated dimension based on the width of the screen (minus the spacing)...

Every cell in my data array has got a position index, I can thus easily find out whether a cell is positioned right or left based base on it (odd / even)

Any help is gladly appreciated

Comment: I would try to subclass the default flow layout, override the methods that calculate the frame of each cell and modify the return value to have the offset.

Comment: @EmilioPelaez I have already subclassed the flow layout, but I'm not sure how I would set the top offset for say the odd cells to be different than the even ones. For instance it's actually just the first odd cells which would have to be lower than the 0 indexed cell, all others would then kinda have the same offset again... hope it makes sense ;)

Comment: I might not be seeing the whole picture, but the way I see it, all cells in the right, which would have an odd `indexPath.item` value, need to be offset by `x`. I would subclass `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` and override `layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath`. If `indexPath.item` is even, return super, otherwise, call super and store the result, update the frame to a new rect offset by `x` and return that updated value.

Comment: @EmilioPelaez not sure I follow regarding return super or call super. May you explain or show and snippet demonstrating what you mean? besides, the offset I'm struggling with is rather the first offset on the y axis for the first odd item in the right column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I would implement a subclass of `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` to achieve what you want.

```
class OffsetFlowLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout {
    var verticalOffset: CGFloat = 0

    override func prepare() {
        super.prepare()
        verticalOffset = 100 // Calculate offset here
    }

    override func layoutAttributesForItem(at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes? {
        guard let attributes = super.layoutAttributesForItem(at: indexPath) else { return nil }
        guard remainder(Double(indexPath.row), 2) != 0 else { return attributes }
        //  For each item in the right column, offset the y value of it's origin
        attributes.frame.origin.y += verticalOffset
        return attributes
    }
}
```

As you can see, on our implementation of `layoutAttributesForItem` the first thing we do is to call super and store the value it returns. Then we check the index and if we are on the left column, we return what super gave us, which would be the "default" value.

If we're on the right column, we modify the attributes object to move the frame of the cell by the offset we want, and then return that one.

NOTE: I haven't tested this. There's a chance the `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` uses the previous cells to layout the next cells, in which case you would only need to modify the first element in the right column, just change `guard remainder(Double(indexPath.row), 2) != 0 else { return attributes }` to `guard indexPath.row == 1 else { return attributes }`

Comment: I've used the same approach for creating snappable Collection View headers, worked like a charm

Comment: @AlexanderTkachenko Apple added a property to `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` called `sectionHeadersPinToVisibleBounds` that does just that ;)

Comment: Wow, thanks, it's awesome!) Will definitely try this when we'll drop an iOS 8 support